# Excel Visual Basic code versioning

Tags: git, excel, versioning, vba

I have a project that requires some VB code written in Excel and I'd like to version it under git. Unfortunately the code is embedded in an excel file and diff shows bunch of excel metadata instead of code changes. I tried to import the foo.vb file from the disc to the VBAProject but excel copied it so changes made to the foo.vb are not visible in the VBAProject. Is there a way to save vb files outside of the excel ?

Thanks

Comment: I have never worked with git but see if [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131605/best-way-to-do-version-control-for-ms-excel) and [THIS](http://culverden.org.uk/blog/69) helps?

Comment: In fact quite few links popped up on google search. See if [ANY](https://www.google.co.in/search?newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=git+and+excel+vba+versioning&oq=git+and+excel+vba+versioning&gs_l=hp.3...1195.6574.0.6753.29.29.0.0.0.0.408.3548.13j12j3j0j1.29.0....0...1c.1.38.hp..11.18.1629.0.Qw2HmD2on7Y) helps you?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855996/flushing-changes-made-to-vbproject-vbcomponents-in-excel-using-vba