# TFS for Microsoft Excel files

Tags: excel, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am using Team Foundation Services (TFS 2012) for development projects.

*I want to know if TFS can be used for version-control of Excel files?*

Specifically:

- I need to commit changes; Is this done within Excel or externally? How?
- I need to resolve conflicts; Is this done within Excel or externally? How?
- I need to compare my current Excel document changes vs. the Original in Source control; Is this done within Excel or externally? How?

Comment: You asked about TFS, but here is a question about good source control options for Excel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131605/best-way-to-do-version-control-for-ms-excel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can checkin/checkout Excel files using TFS but since Excel files are in a binary format (unless they are pure `.CSV` files) you will get limited usefulness trying to compare versions.

You would most likely use [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) or similar Windows Shell Extension to commit your file when you are done editing it. You can also add your Excel document to a Solution/Project in Visual Studio and version control it using Visual Studio, but attempting to open the file would result in Excel launching.

Because Excel files are binary files **Comparison** would be manual processes where a human visually compares documents side by side using two instance of Excel. **Conflict Resolution** would require the same process, with the added step of a human modifying one excel document or another. In both cases you would want to make a copy of the file and edit the copy, then either copy it over or manually transpose each edit.

You could possibly try *Excel 2016* to save in [Open Document Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) and/or CSV and then use regular diff tools for comparison, merge and conflict resolution (this would be true for any Version Control System.) However, this would not be an ideal workflow for the typical office employee (maybe okay for programmers.)

Services like [Box](http://www.box.com), [Google Drive](http://www.google.com/drive) or [Sharepoint Online](https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-online-collaboration-software) currently provide a better solution to these problems, and if you want to retain docs in your source control system you can regularly commit whatever you have stored in a purpose-built system.

Comment: I just saw this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181675(v=vs.110).aspx  But cant i add new excel files, add modify it in different users and do checkin files etc as we do for VS projects. I am looking for multiple users changing the excel at a time and then when required it can be checked in.

Comment: That link is about work items: "To add or modify Team Foundation work items by using Microsoft Excel or Microsoft Project, you connect your worksheet or project plan to a team project."

Comment: ok. So which link i can refer for using Excel with TFS? Whether it is available?