# Using Git with XLAM Excel Plugins

Tags: git, excel, vba

Is there any way I can use Git for the development of Excel xlam plugins? It seems like they are compiled and not text...

Maybe there is a way to split them in various text files and then automatically recomplile them after each git commits?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to do Version Control for MS Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131605/best-way-to-do-version-control-for-ms-excel): the accepted answer uses Bazaar, not Git, but otherwise it can be a usable way.