# Adding File version Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, version

I want to add and change file version in cell `P76` every time there is a change in file.

I tried this function but it is showing Excel version and it is not changing.

```
Function ExcelVersion()
    ExcelVersion = Application.Version
End Function
```

and in cell `P76` (Sheet2)

```
=ExcelVersion()
```

I want it to show like `VERSION 001` and every time (sheet2) update of change it change to next eg `VERSION 001` to `VERSION 002` and so on and in cell `P77` (Sheet2) Dates and time of update.

I also try to add this

```
Private Sub submit_Click()     
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Cells(P76).value = "VERSION 00" & i + 1
End Sub
```

but not working

Comment: Application.Version will give the Excel version but not the change versions of your workbook,should try in some other way

Comment: By the way what do you mean by every time, are expecting this to happen every times user modify data and save it, then you code should increase version number

Comment: `Application.Version` is the Excel Version - as in 14.0 is Excel 2010, 11.0 is Excel 2003.  If you want the update version you'll have to create a global variable and increment each time there's an update.

Comment: @Siva Your second comment is what i am looking for

Comment: Sorry I can't give you code as I'm texting via mobile. You have predefined before close function.In that function you can write code

Comment: I found this. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131605/best-way-to-do-version-control-for-ms-excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131605/best-way-to-do-version-control-for-ms-excel)

Comment: @AndreTurina i read that earlier before posting question that is for saving file i just want counter in cell P76 which should update on change of Sheet

Comment: I know its very simple code i don know how to apply eg i = integer  P76 = i + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in "ThisWorkbook". It will add the version number without the "Version" string. I would recommend adding "Version" in an adjacent cell in order to keep it simple.

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("P76").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("P76").Value + 1
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("P77").Value = Now

End Sub
```

If you need "version" to be in the same cell as the number itself, comment and I will edit my response to reflect that functionality.

Also, this will not prevent users from editing the version number, time etc. just so you are aware.

Comment: it works well i added Version in adjacent cell with little alignment looks good

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. It is placed in the workbook BeforeSave event. In cell P67 you would have the word "Version:" followed by the version number. This text before the version number has 9 characters, including the space.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim varVersion As Long
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
varVersion = Right(Range("P67").Text, Len(Range("P67")) - 9)
Range("P67") = "Version: " & varVersion + 1
Range("P77").Value = Format(Now, "dd mmm yyyy")

End Sub
```