# Method to compare VBA change in xlsm file in Visual Studio 12

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2012, tfs, version-control, vba

Just like we can compare .NET, javascripts files in Visual Studio and point out the exact changes that have been made between two separate versions, similarly is there a way to compare VBA of an xlsm file between two versions in Visual Studio 12?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, we cannot achieve that.

We cannot compare the .xlsm files with hte VBA code directly. We can only compare the text files in VS.

So, you could export all your VBA code into text for source control. Thus you can compare the different versions same as .NET, javascripts files.

There is an excel addin : https://github.com/hilkoc/vbaDeveloper.

It can export all your vba code automatically, as soon as you save your workbook. You can also easily import it again when you open a workbook.

Another workaround is comparing with other tools:

- [Excel: Extract VBA code to text files (for diffing)](https://www.pretentiousname.com/excel_extractvba/index.html)
- [VbaDiff](http://vbadiff.com/)
- [DiffEngineX](https://www.florencesoft.com/diff-compare-excel-vba-visual-basic-for-applications.html)

Other threads for your reference:

- [Best way to do Version Control for MS Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131605/best-way-to-do-version-control-for-ms-excel)
- [Excel VBA and Version Control](http://tech.popdata.org/unicorn-2-version-control/)

[image]

Comment: No, I am still using Notepad++ to see the difference between modules.